# GridView not binding DataTable from DataSet

Tags: c#, ado.net

Seeking help from friends

I have loaded 3 tables from database to `DataSet` using `DataReader` but I'm unable to bind it to a `GridView`.

```
protected void GetStudReport(Object o, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mycon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        List<string> lstQstn = new List<string>();

        mycon.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from scord_mark_table where stu_ID=@StID", mycon);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("StID", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "stu_ID"));
        cmd.Parameters["@StID"].Value = drpDnSearch3.SelectedValue;
        MySqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtScrTbl = new DataTable("ScoreTable");
        dtScrTbl.Load(rdr1);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtScrTbl);
        rdr1.Close();
        cmd = null;

        int i = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> dctSub = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (DataTableReader dtr = ds.CreateDataReader())
        {
            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                lstQstn.Add(dtr["test_id"].ToString());

                while (i <= lstQstn.Count())
                {
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT test_id,subject_id from qution_no_table where test_id='" + lstQstn[i].ToString() + "'", mycon);
                    MySqlDataReader rdr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr2.Read())
                    {
                      dctSub.Add(rdr2["subject_id"].ToString(),rdr2["test_id"].ToString());
                    }
                    rdr2.Close();
                    break;
                }

                i++;


            }
            cmd = null;
        }

        string strTestID="where test_id='";
        i=0;
        foreach (string lst in lstQstn)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                strTestID += @" and test_id='";
            }
            strTestID += lst + @"'";
            i++;
        }


        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from qution_no_table " +strTestID+";"+"SELECT * from out_of_mark_table " +strTestID, mycon);

        MySqlDataReader rdr3 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dtQNoTbl = new DataTable("QstNoTable");
        dtQNoTbl.Load(rdr3);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtQNoTbl);

        rdr3.NextResult();

        // bind the second resultset
        DataTable dtOutMrkTbl = new DataTable("OutOfMarkTable");
        dtOutMrkTbl.Load(rdr3);
        ds.Tables.Add(dtOutMrkTbl);
        rdr3.Close();

        //**
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["OutOfMarkTable"];
        GridView1.DataBind(); //**
     }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the binding is failing? Have you used a debugger to ensure there is data in the DataReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your `rdr3.NextResult()` which advances the reader to the next result(if any). But that is already done in [`DataTable.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e06d41f.aspx). From MSDN:

> The Load method consumes the first result set from the loaded
>   IDataReader, and after successful completion, sets the reader's
>   position to the next result set, if any.

So you simply need to omit it. Another option is to use  `DatSet.Load(reader)` instead to add the last two  tables at once:

```
ds.Load(rdr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "QstNoTable","OutOfMarkTable");
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["OutOfMarkTable"];
```

`DataSet.Load` will not  remove existing tables in the `DataSet`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response Mr.Schmelter. But still I am not able to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Aneosh: I assume i've found the reason now, edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank very much Mr.Schmelter for ur precious time spend on this.Its really working !!